# Set or Get cookies for different domains (not on a subdomain)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a file server, or more of a personal CDN, which I want to protect against unauthorized access. Assuming that this personal CDN is accessible through `https://www.personalCDN.com`, and the requests to this file server come from the following domains:

```
1- https://www.Application1.com
2- https://www.Application2.com
3- https://www.WebSite1.com
```

In case I want the authentication layer to be cookie-based in a way that, when the user logs into any of these three domains, a cookie for `https://www.personalCDN.com` would be added to browser, and then it would be used by the main file server, how can I handle this situation in `ASP.Net Core 2.x`? I've read that, writing cookies for other domains is not allowed in JavaScript, does it apply to Asp.Net as well?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a JavaScript limitation, it's a functional limitation, in general. Cookies are domain-bound. They can only be written on the domain where the response originates. Likewise, a cookie can only be read by the domain that set it. This is for security reasons, and there's absolute no way around it.

What you would need is a SSO (single sign on) solution, which is not a trivial thing to set up. You essentially have one server that acts as the auth gateway. Your other websites redirect users to that server to login, the user logs in on the auth gateway, where a cookie is set for that domain (i.e. auth.domain.com). This keeps the user logged in on the gateway. Then, the user is redirected back to the originating site, with a token. That token is then validated via an API backchannel to the auth gateway. If the token is valid, then the originating website "logs in" the user, setting a cookie for its domain, as well. Rinse and repeat with all your other websites.

For something like your CDN, you would likely need a site hosted on a subdomain of that same domain (since the CDN itself wouldn't be able to coordinate the auth process). That site, then, would set a wildcard domain cookie, which would be usable by the CDN as well.

You can either set up all this infrastructure yourself (not recommended), or there's third-party libraries like IdentityServer that could ease implementation. Additionally, you can outsource the whole shebang to a third-party provider like Auth0, where it essentially becomes your gateway.

Comment: Unfortunately these options are out of question here. The CDN is already elsewhere with a different domain, no federated identity works here due to certain reasons which is a long story.